# Debo crear una única función que genere una información para cada familia de aves

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio

el archivo contiene observaciones de 5 familias de aves, se trata de un data frame de 19 variables y 140059 objetos. La función debe de tener como argumentos la base de datos *Seabirds* y el nombre de la familia.

Automáticamente, al colocar esto: generador_familia(Seabirds, "Nombre de la familia x"), debe generar la sgte. información:

```
En la Familia X se encontraron _____ especies.
Las especies son: ____
El año con más observaciones fue: ______
La especie con más observaciones fue: _____
```

Estaba tratando de usar subset y print como cuerpo de la función pero sale NULL.

```
X year month day decimalLatitude decimalLongitude  kingdom   phylum class
1 2017     8  29       -0.684857        -90.36010 Animalia Chordata  Aves
2 2018    12   4        9.182836        -82.08344 Animalia Chordata  Aves
3 2014     1  29        8.431881        -78.96257 Animalia Chordata  Aves
4 2018    12  31       -0.748180        -90.31355 Animalia Chordata  Aves
5 2018    12  20       -0.748180        -90.31355 Animalia Chordata  Aves
6 2018    12  31       -0.748180        -90.31355 Animalia Chordata  Aves
7 2018    12  31       -0.748180        -90.31355 Animalia Chordata  Aves

order          family    genus               species
Suliformes Fregatidae  Fregata   Fregata magnificens
Suliformes Fregatidae  Fregata   Fregata magnificens
Suliformes Fregatidae  Fregata   Fregata magnificens
Suliformes Fregatidae  Fregata   Fregata magnificens
Suliformes Fregatidae  Fregata   Fregata magnificens
Suliformes Fregatidae  Fregata   Fregata magnificens
Suliformes Fregatidae  Fregata   Fregata magnificens

DistCoast    chl_MC sstd_MC   bathymetry      sshc     slope
       NA       NA      NA  249.8359375        NA 3.8300328
6236.957        NA  28.625   -0.8773139 0.1859086 0.8092361
2202.494 3.2934225  27.135   19.1291695 0.2716656 0.8821311
2211.489        NA      NA   12.5483532        NA 1.1031138
2211.489        NA      NA   12.5483532        NA 1.1031138
2211.489        NA      NA   12.5483532        NA 1.1031138
2211.489        NA      NA   12.5483532        NA 1.1031138

#El archivo consta de varias columnas:
    # year:año de colecta
    # month: mes de colecta
    # decimalLatitude: Latidud del punto de observación
    # decimalLongitude: Longitud del punto de observación
    # kingdom: Reino
    # phylum: el phylum
    # class: la clase
    # order: el orden
    # family: la familia
    # genus: el género
    # species: el nombre de la especie
    # DistCoast: la distancia a la costa en la cual fue colectada la muestra
    # chl_MC: clorofila a a una escala climatológica (promedio compuesto de 15 años)
    # sstd_MC: temperatura superficial del mar a escala climatológica
    # bathymetry: profuncidad en metros
    # sshc: variación de la altura superficial
    # slope: pendiente (calculada como la tasa de variación de la batimetría)
```

Ahi se muestran las 7 primeras filas de Seabirds con las 19 variables.
El archivo contiene observaciones de aves marinas de las familias Sulidae (Piqueros), Fregatidae (Fragatas), Laridae (Gaviotas, Gaviotines), Procellariidae (Petreles y Pardelas) e Hydrobatidae (Golondrinas de mar). Las observaciones fueron obtenidas desde el 2012 al 2019.

Tengo el numero de observaciones por año de todas las especies

```
observaciones_por_año <- table(Seabirds$year)
observaciones_por_año

2012  2013  2014  2015  2016  2017  2018  2019 
7540  8653 14976 21230 22366 30082 34957   255
```

Sin embargo, la función tiene que arrojar los resultados por especie, no en total.

[Este es el archivo Seabirds completo en excel](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zPtdlnP6jAqrv_kkGqiFl_eqdHQB1oSvS7Ol1GMC0Ho/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Si, ya veo el error. Está en la línea 3. Lo he resuelto gracias a mis poderes de adivinación, porque obviamente si no pones el código no sé cómo esperas que alguien adivine donde está el error... Te recomiendo leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) si quieres obtener respuestas de verdad, y bienvenida a SOes

Comment: @Benito-B si, tienes razón jaja ya añadí más info.

Comment: Noemí, si esto es una tarea académica, deberías agregar el código de lo que hayas intentado hasta ahora y explicar que dificultades has tenido. La idea no es que la comunidad resuelva tu tarea sino ayudarte a que tu lo hagas.

Answer (score 0):

Tu primer problema es "filtrar" los datos según la familia, puedes hacerlo así:

```
# Subset
nom_familia <- 'Procellariidae'

familia <- df[df$family == nom_familia,]

# O bien
familia <- subset(familia, family == nom_familia)
```

Lo siguiente, es saber cuales son las especies y la cantidad de las mismas:

```
# Especies por familia
especies_x_familia = unique(familia$species)
especies_x_familia

 [1] "Puffinus subalaris"         "Pterodroma phaeopygia"      "Puffinus griseus"          
 [4] "Puffinus bulleri"           "Puffinus pacificus"         "Pseudobulweria rostrata"   
 [7] "Puffinus creatopus"         "Procellaria aequinoctialis" "Procellaria parkinsoni"    
[10] "Puffinus lherminieri"       "Puffinus opisthomelas"      "Puffinus puffinus"         
[13] "Puffinus nativitatis"       "Procellaria westlandica"    "Puffinus carneipes"  

cant_especies_x_familia <- length(especies_x_familia)
cant_especies_x_familia

[1] 15
```

Y usando `table()` podemos obtener las observaciones por año, y con `which.max()` aquel con el mayor número:

```
# años con mayor cantidad de observaciones
table(familia$year)

2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 
 346  350  691  954  735 1605 1540    4 

anio_mas_observaciones <- names(which.max(table(familia$year)))
anio_mas_observaciones

[1] "2017"
```

Y el proceso con las especies es similar:

```
# especies con mayor cantidad de observaciones
table(familia$species)

Procellaria aequinoctialis     Procellaria parkinsoni    Procellaria westlandica    Pseudobulweria rostrata 
                        21                         35                          2                         24 
     Pterodroma phaeopygia           Puffinus bulleri         Puffinus carneipes         Puffinus creatopus 
                      1265                          1                          1                        186 
          Puffinus griseus       Puffinus lherminieri       Puffinus nativitatis      Puffinus opisthomelas 
                       157                         13                         12                          4 
        Puffinus pacificus          Puffinus puffinus         Puffinus subalaris 
                       236                          3                       4265 


especie_mas_observaciones <- names(which.max(table(familia$species)))
especie_mas_observaciones

[1] "Puffinus subalaris"
```

El último tema, sería integrar todo en una sola función, y para construir la cadena final te recomiendo usar `paste()`, por ejemplo:

```
paste("En la Familia", nom_familia, "se encontraron",
      cant_especies_x_familia, "especies.")

[1] "En la Familia Procellariidae se encontraron 15 especies."
```